# Adding a scrollbar to a custom QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have a custom `QWidget` A, which contains another custom `QWidget` B. I want to add a scrollbar to the `Qwidget` B. I tried adding a `QScrollArea`, but it covers the entire window of `QWidget` A. How do I ensure that the scrollbar is for only `QWidget` B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First replace QWidget B with the QScrollArea and set it up so that it is where you want it to be. Then simple add QWidget B to the QScrollArea.

Comment: thanks. that really helped, and worked! I also used setResizable(true) for a better effect